# Bertini's theorem and composite with pencils

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a normal projective variety over an algebraically closed field $k.$ Let $|D|$ be a linear system of effective Cartier divisors without base points, and assume that $|D|$ is not composite with a pencil, meaning that if $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^n_k$ is the morphism $|D|$ determines, then $dim f(X) \geq 2.$ I would then want to show that every divisor in $|D|$ is connected.

Hartshorne gives the hint of using Stein factorization, together with the following corollary:
Let $X$ be a normal projective variety of dimension $\geq 2$ over an algebraically closed field $k.$ Let $Y$ be a closed subset of codimension $1$ which is the support of an effective ample divisor. Then $Y$ is connected.

So my thought was to use these hints, so consider the Stein factorization $X \xrightarrow{f'} X' \xrightarrow{g} \mathbb{P}^n_k.$ We know that $f'$ has connected fibers and is closed, so I assume that it would be enough to check that if $\delta \in |D|,$ and $Z$ is the associated scheme, then $f'(Z)$ is connected. But maybe this isn't the right tactic, since I am not sure how to pushforward Cartier divisors.

Any hints/solutions would be appreciated. This is for self-study and from Hartshorne's book.

Comment: You need to check that the inverse image under $f'$ of an ample, effective divisor in $X'$ is a connected subset of $X$.  This is not about pushforward of Cartier divisors.  By the way, this is not how Bertini proved his theorem; he certainly did not have at hand the Lemma of Enriques-Severi-Zariski.  There is a lovely article of Kleiman that explains Bertini's two famous theorems and the original proofs.

Comment: @JasonStarr I'm sure you're right. I agree that if we know that a divisor is connected in $X',$ then it it connected in $X.$ However, there are some things that's confusing me:  
1. Say I have $\delta \in |D|.$ Why is the support of this scheme the inverse image of a ample divisor in $X'?$  
2. Why must the corresponding divisor in $X'$ be connected?

Comment: By definition of the morphism $f$, every divisor in $X$ that is in the complete linear system $|D|$ is of the form $f^*H$ for a unique Cartier divisor $H$ in the complete linear system of the invertible sheaf $\mathcal{O}(1)$ on $\mathbb{P}^n$.  Of course $f^*H$ equals $(f')^*(g^*H)$.  Please read the statement of the Lemma of Enriques-Severi-Zariski in Hartshorne's textbook.

Comment: @JasonStarr So let me see if I get this correctly. We have that if $H$ is in the linear system given by $\mathcal{O}(1),$ then $H$ is ample. Now, the map $X' \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^n_k$ is finite so that $g^* H$ is ample as well. We also see that $X'$ is normal and of dimension $\geq 2.$ So the lemma of Enriques-Severi-Zariski gives that $g^* H$ is connected?

Comment: Yes, all of what you wrote is correct.  Finally, since $f'$ is surjective connected (geometric) fibers, the inverse image of a connected subset of $X'$ is a connected subset of $X$.  Once again, this is not how Bertini proved his theorem.